# Removing all script tags from html with JS Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to strip script tags out of this HTML at Pastebin:

> http://pastebin.com/mdxygM0a

I tried using the below regular expression:

```
html.replace(/<script.*>.*<\/script>/ims, " ")
```

But it does not remove all of the script tags in the HTML. It only removes in-line scripts. I'm looking for some regex that can remove all of the script tags (in-line and multi-line). It would be highly appreciated if a test is carried out on my sample http://pastebin.com/mdxygM0a

Comment: Please don't do it this way (if it involves any user input at all). Just take a look at all the ways in which it could be got around if you don't deal with *every* case - http://html5sec.org/

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think i will just use JQuery to remove them.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Attempting to remove HTML markup using a regular expression is problematic. You don't know what's in there as script or attribute values. One way is to insert it as the innerHTML of a div, remove any script elements and return the innerHTML, e.g.

```
  function stripScripts(s) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
      scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
  }

alert(
 stripScripts('<span><script type="text/javascript">alert(\'foo\');<\/script><\/span>')
);
```

Note that at present, browsers will not execute the script if inserted using the innerHTML property, and likely never will especially as the element is not added to the document.

Comment: Thanks alot for this. I used your approach with jQuery and its perfect.

Comment: This does not seem to work in IE8 div.innerHTML = s; does nothing, if i check the value of div.innerHTML its ""

Comment: It works in every browser I've tested, including IE 6. I can't try IE 8 for a couple of days but pretty certain I tested there and it works. I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks! Beware of jQuery.html(), is does execute the script:

    $('<div>').html('<script>alert(1)</script>')

Comment: My only suggestion is to pass the name of the tag in and call it stripTag.

Comment: Would any of the down–voters care to say why? If there's an issue with the answer, it may be helpful to point it out.

Comment: Maybe some browsers evaluate scripts when doing it that way? Just a guess (like already mentioned in my answer)

Comment: @ThiefMaster—browsers haven't previously and do not now evaluate scripts added using innerHTML, [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) specifies that they must not in future. Any browser that did so now would "break the web". Currently there are several methods for executing scripts when adding them to the DOM, innerHTML provides a safe way of inserting markup and ensuring scripts aren't executed so I don't think anyone is keen to change that.

Comment: @RobG ...older browsers (IE7/8) process out other elements (e.g. style elements), rendering the result by return div.innerHTML corrupted.

Comment: Concerning my comment above: this was actually because the script tag was the first element.

Comment: @scader—if style elements are to be preserved, they should be added as the innerHTML of a head element, not a div, and then placed into the head using DOM methods.

Comment: I think that's right solution, but it has some disadvantages. It won't strip scripts if some whitespaces placed before "script" word. And indeed such html is possible, so if someone insert script like "< script>< / script>" i believe browser fill fix this, but this solution doesn't work with such strings. By the way I think browser don't run scripts before you append your newly created div with script inside to the DOM itself. @RobG What do you think?

Comment: @Rantiev—not sure about that. It relies on the host parser recognising a script element. So if the parser corrects "< script" to "<script" then it will be converted to a script element and removed, but if it leaves it as "< script" then it will be treated as plain text and not be executed. But happy to be proved wrong if you have test case. ;-)

Answer (score 130):

jQuery uses a regex to remove script tags in some cases and I'm pretty sure its devs had a damn good reason to do so. Probably some browser *does* execute scripts when inserting them using `innerHTML`.

Here's the regex:

```
/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script\s*>/gi
```

And before people start crying "but regexes for HTML are evil": [Yes, they are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) - but for script tags they are safe because of the special behaviour - a `<script>` section may not contain `</script>` at all unless it should end at this position. So matching it with a regex is easily possible. This will work with trailing whitespace inside the closing tag.

Comment: If you set the innerHTML property of an element in a document to markup that contains a script element with the defer attribute, it will be executed in some browsers (such as IE). However, if the same markup is assigned to an element that is not in the document, or the defer attribute is not set, the script is not executed. Using a regular expression is problematic, it will fail in some cases. Prototype.js uses a different RegExp: `/<script[^>]*>([\\S\\s]*?)<\/script>/img`.

Comment: Reference to the jQuery regex: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/ajax.js#L14

Comment: `but for script tags they are safe`

It fails here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18052486/2570622
`<script type="text/javascript">
 var test1 = "</script>"; 
 var test2 = '<script>';
 </script>`

Comment: `</script>` is not permitted inside a script tag. It always ends it.

Comment: won't work with ""< script>< / script>" such strings are possible in HTML.

Comment: @Rantiev after tests, ThiefMaster is totally right, even inside a string, `</ script>` ends the script

Answer (score 49):

Regexes are beatable, but if you have a string version of HTML that you don't want to inject into a DOM, they may be the best approach. You may want to put it in a loop to handle something like:

```
<scr<script>Ha!</script>ipt> alert(document.cookie);</script>
```

Here's what I did, using the jquery regex from above:

```
var SCRIPT_REGEX = /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;
while (SCRIPT_REGEX.test(text)) {
    text = text.replace(SCRIPT_REGEX, "");
}
```

Comment: This works well, but needs modifying per neongrau answer above to allow for trailing spaces in closing script tag - which are still valid.

Comment: You are Awesome :)

Answer (score 18):

This Regex should work too:

```
<script(?:(?!\/\/)(?!\/\*)[^'"]|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|\/\/.*(?:\n)|\/\*(?:(?:.|\s))*?\*\/)*?<\/script>
```

It even allows to have "problematic" variable strings like these inside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var test1 = "</script>";
   var test2 = '\'</script>';
   var test1 = "\"</script>";
   var test1 = "<script>\"";
   var test2 = '<scr\'ipt>';
   /* </script> */
   // </script>
   /* ' */
   // var foo=" '
</script>
```

It seams that jQuery and Prototype fail on these ones...

**Edit July 31 '17:** Added a) non-capturing groups for better performance (and no empty groups) and b) support for JavaScript comments.

Comment: So regexes for HTML are evil after all! Any scripts that can beat your regex?

Comment: I'm actually using evil regex to parse HTML in several cases and it seams to work well. I just edited the post and enhanced the regex with support for escaped quotes in JavaScript variables. (that would have beaten my regex :-)

Comment: I am using this regex in Notepad++ to clear the HTML code of unwanted script tags and it's been serving me very well.

Comment: you regex is interesting for its ability to ignore nested strings.. but i would suggest replacing the beginning by `<script(?:` or else i get an always empty capturing group. Talking about that, do you see a solution for your regex to capture the js content? It would be interesting not to have to remove the tags separately..

Comment: actually, after tests, i found scripts that are ignored by your regex (didn't find why, the exemple itself is a bit long, and surprisingly broke the regex when i removed a comment section -probably something about even or uneven number of `'` or `"`-). But the worse is that some comments on this post are totally right: even inside a string, a `</script>` ends the script, this is normal behaviour, so your regex produces different result than DOM method.. too bad, i was enthusiast :/

Comment: Thanks @Kaddath for your comments. Edited the Regex, see note. Capturing the JS content shouldn't be too hard either, tho it's not part of the question.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you have to resort to Regex based script tag cleanup. At least add a white-space to the closing tag in the form of

```
</script\s*>
```

Otherwise things like

```
<script>alert(666)</script   >
```

would remain since trailing spaces after tagnames are valid.

Comment: Vote up, but please don't post such a thing a separate answer. it has to be a comment.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove all JavaScript code from some HTML text, then removing `<script>` tags isn't enough, because JavaScript can still live in "onclick", "onerror", "href" and other attributes.

Try out this npm module which handles all of this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-js

Comment: Good point about the onevent attributes. If you don't trust the string, you really shouldn't be inserting it into your page as HTML! There are too many tricks to get around blacklist-based solutions!

Answer (score 4):

Why not using jQuery.parseHTML() http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without a regular expression.  Simply cast your HTML string to an HTML node using [**`document.createElement()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), find all scripts with [**`element.getElementsByTagName('script')`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), and then just [**`remove()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) them!

Fun fact:  SO's demo does not like it when you create an element with a `<script>` tag!  The snippet below will not run, but it does work at: [**Full Working Demo at JSBin.com**](https://jsbin.com/lanakivuba/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

```js
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = "<p>Valid paragraph.</p><p>Another valid paragraph.</p><script>Dangerous scripting!!!</script><p>Last final paragraph.</p>";

var scripts = el.getElementsByTagName( 'script' ); // Live NodeList of your anchor elements

for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
  var script = scripts[i];
  script.remove();
}

console.log(el.innerHTML);
```

This is a much cleaner solution than a regex, imho.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed a requirement to parse out the page title AND and have all the other goodness of jQuery, minus it firing scripts. Here is my solution that seems to work.

```
        $.get('/somepage.htm', function (data) {
            // excluded code to extract title for simplicity
            var bodySI = data.indexOf('<body>') + '<body>'.length,
                bodyEI = data.indexOf('</body>'),
                body = data.substr(bodySI, bodyEI - bodySI),
                $body;

            body = body.replace(/<script[^>]*>/gi, ' <!-- ');
            body = body.replace(/<\/script>/gi, ' --> ');

            //console.log(body);

            $body = $('<div>').html(body);
            console.log($body.html());
        });
```

This kind of shortcuts worries about script because you are not trying to remove out the script tags and content, instead you are replacing them with comments rendering schemes to break them useless as you would have comments delimiting your script declarations.

Let me know if that still presents a problem as it will help me too.

Comment: This sounds smart and fairly unobtrusive. 
Did you have good results? Can anyone come up with problems to this approach?

Comment: I'm controlling the pages being requested. I did not do rigorous testing to try to break it with malicious intent so I would not put faith in it for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var text = text.replace(/<script[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/script>)[^])*<\/script>/g, "")
```

Comment: Whilst I have used this, and it seems to work, regex101 says there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a variety of shell scripts you can use to strip out different elements.

```
# doctype
find . -regex ".*\.\(html\|py\)$" -type f -exec sed -i "s/<\!DOCTYPE\s\+html[^>]*>/<\!DOCTYPE html>/gi" {} \;

# meta charset
find . -regex ".*\.\(html\|py\)$" -type f -exec sed -i "s/<meta[^>]*content=[\"'][^\"']*utf-8[\"'][^>]*>/<meta charset=\"utf-8\">/gi" {} \;

# script text/javascript
find . -regex ".*\.\(html\|py\)$" -type f -exec sed -i "s/\(<script[^>]*\)\(\stype=[\"']text\/javascript[\"']\)\(\s\?[^>]*>\)/\1\3/gi" {} \;

# style text/css
find . -regex ".*\.\(html\|py\)$" -type f -exec sed -i "s/\(<style[^>]*\)\(\stype=[\"']text\/css[\"']\)\(\s\?[^>]*>\)/\1\3/gi" {} \;

# html xmlns
find . -regex ".*\.\(html\|py\)$" -type f -exec sed -i "s/\(<html[^>]*\)\(\sxmlns=[\"'][^\"']*[\"']\)\(\s\?[^>]*>\)/\1\3/gi" {} \;

# html xml:lang
find . -regex ".*\.\(html\|py\)$" -type f -exec sed -i "s/\(<html[^>]*\)\(\sxml:lang=[\"'][^\"']*[\"']\)\(\s\?[^>]*>\)/\1\3/gi" {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

/(?:(?!</s\w)<[^<]*)*</s\w*/gi; - Removes any sequence in any combination with

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use regex to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1444609)

Consider the following string:

```
var str = "<script>var false_closing_tag = '</script>';</script>";
var stripped = str.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, '');
console.log(stripped); // Logs: ';</script>
```

The current, top voted regex answer will fail to fully remove this. (Try it). I can't even run that in the SO editor or JSFiddle because both of them are using insufficient means to parse the code before running it.

And the other option which involves adding it to a `<div>` element and then pulling the `innerText` of the div has negative side effects as well: It will actually run the code (which is a security concern) and it will remove ALL HTML and not just script tags.

**The Solution**

You need to actually parse the text:

```
function stripScriptTags(str){
  if(typeof str !== 'string') {
    return false;
  }
  var opened_quote_type = null;
  var in_script_tag = false;
  var string_buffer = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(opened_quote_type === null && ["'", '"', '`'].includes(str[i])){
      opened_quote_type = str[i];
    }else if(opened_quote_type === str[i]){
      opened_quote_type = null;
    }
    if(str.length > i+7 && str.toUpperCase().substring(i, i+7) === '<SCRIPT'){
      i += 7;
      in_script_tag = true;
    }
    if(in_script_tag && 
       opened_quote_type === null && 
       str.length > i+9 && 
       str.toUpperCase().substring(i, i+9) === '</SCRIPT>'
    ){
      i += 9;
      in_script_tag = false;
    }
    if(!in_script_tag){
      string_buffer.push(str[i]);
    }
  }
  return string_buffer.join('');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
$("your_div_id").remove();
```

or

```
 $("your_div_id").html("");
```

Comment: That would strip everything, not just script tags