# Screen scraping with jQuery on PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to do a screen scrape using jquery in a PhoneGap application. The problem is that when I load the target HTML into the current dom so I can use selectors, it attempts to execute the javascript:

```
        $(function() {
            $.get('http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/csfb:ind', function(data) {
                var elements = $("<div>").html(data)[0].getElementsByClassName("price")[0];
            });
        });
```

The get works fine and pulls in the html, but once it starts loading, it tries to execute the javascript.

Is there anyway to strip out all javascript tags?

Comment: This feels like a chicken and egg problem. If you're stripping all JavaScript, how can jQuery gets run? If you're putting the stripping part in <head> when the script runs, the <body> is not parsed yet. This problem is not trivial at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the most reliable way as any parsing you come up with on your own may not work in all cases.

[Removing all script tags from html with JS Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression)

If I copy the stripScripts function from that answer:

```
function stripScripts(s) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
        scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
}
$(function () {
    $.get('http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/csfb:ind', function (data) {
        var elements = $("<div>").html(stripScripts(data))[0].getElementsByClassName("price")[0];
    });
});
```