# prevent javascript of loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div for temporary store the code of a webpage, however, the page contains javascript, what should I do to block those javascript so that my program would not be interrupted? I use the code below to load

```
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
dataType:'html',
cache:false,
url:file,
success:function(html){
     ...
     ...
     $('#temp').html(html)
}
});
```

Comment: You want to remove some JavaScript from the data you are getting back from an AJAX call?

Comment: @Lix something like that, but not actually remove because I need to pull back and update the original one

Comment: Do you have access to the code you are loading?  Can you perhaps change the functionality of the script to only execute when you call it?  I mean taking the code out of a document ready function and placing it in your own function to be called when you are ready...

Answer (score 1):

The `.html(string)` function will use `innerHTML` which evaluates all scripts. You could use `.text(string)` instead to temporarily save your HTML content.

```
$('#temp').text(html);
```

Then retrieve it later and execute it if you want

```
$('#element').html($('#temp').text());
```

If you just want to get rid of all `<script>` tags, though, use a simple regex replace.

** **Update** **

StackOverflow [already has some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression/6660151#6660151) about removing `<script>` tags in a string.

Comment: [Here is an answer with the regular expression method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6660151/558021)

Answer (score -1):

It's possible you may just need to make your ajax request a synchronous request, but your question is a little unclear, and most likely not possible.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Let me clarify since I got downvoted:
You can simply remove script tags if your script runs before other code pieces in the page, however I don't think this is an acceptable answer because it may cause parts of your page relying on these scripts to stop functioning.

If scripts are already running, removing the script tags might not be enough, or might generate errors also causing your script to not run.

You need to provide a better example of exactly what you are doing to get a clear answer.