# Find <style> tag by class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styles, find

I'm using AJAX to fetch some HTML markup. I want to append some style tags (with a class) from the fetched markup to my own document using `find()`. However, jQuery does not seem to like the following approach.

(link removed due to lack of reputation)

Could someone shed some light on why this does not work, and point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

### Solutions

- Making it a native element first (and removing script tags as extra precaution) works. http://jsfiddle.net/T6QCR/5/
- Also, a lot simpler, using `innerHTML` instead of `.html()` works, as setting innerHTML does not evaluate scripts and allows `.find()` to function. http://jsfiddle.net/T6QCR/8/
- Also, laconbass' answer below.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Parse the HTML chunk rather than just passing it to jQuery

From the [jQuery function documentation for the case you are using](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> (...) if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to
>   create new DOM elements as described by the HTML. Then a jQuery object
>   is created and returned that refers to these elements. You can perform
>   any of the usual jQuery methods on this object.
>
> (...)
>
> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as
>   it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is
>   handled by the browser's innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery
>   creates a new  element and sets the innerHTML property of the
>   element to the HTML snippet that was passed in.
>
> (...)
>
> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery
>   uses the browser"s .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and
>   insert it into the current document. During this process, some
>   browsers filter out certain elements such as  ,  , or 
>    elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be
>   representative of the original string passed.

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) recomends ussing `$.parseHtml()`

> For explicit parsing of a string to HTML, use the $.parseHTML()
>   method.

### `$.filter` rather than `$.find`

As you noted, [`$.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) does not work on this example. I had succeed replacing it with a [`$.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) call.

```
// this works
$html.filter('.test');
// this doesn't works
$html.find('.test');

// better if you filter also by tag
// surely you will have more tags other than <style> on the retrieved html
$html.filter('style.test');
```

### See how this applies to your example on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCWzb/1/).

Comment: Very interesting. I came up with the following results: http://jsfiddle.net/T6QCR/7/. It seems `.find()` just doesn't work on style tags. Even when they are just regular nodes. (while using parseHTML)

Comment: I see that `$.parseHtml(html)` returns an array (with only 1 dimension in your fiddle corresponding to the `<style>` tag). With `$( $.parseHtml(html) )`, you get a jQuery object whose query has `length==1` and stores the `<style>` DOM object. When you do $html.find('.test')` you are trying to find `'.test'` into the `<style>` DOM object, so no results are found.

Comment: Also you are right, `.find()` doesn't works. You can use `$.filter()` instead. Take a look at the update I did to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`body` is not defined, the console gives an indication of this by way of an error, too. If you want to use jQuery to select the markup body and append the style then you will need to use an appropriate selector:

```
$("body").append($style);
```

Comment: This was a mistake in the code example, my apologies. The style still will not be `.find`-ed. See http://jsfiddle.net/T6QCR/4/
When using `console.log($style)` to check what the length of $style.length is, it says 0. It should say 1 and contain the style element.

Answer (score 0):

`<style>` element can't has `class` attribute, because `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

This code shoud work:

```
var html = '<html><head><style>aaa</style></head></html>';
var $html = $.parseHTML(html);

$.each($html, function(i, el) {
    if(el.nodeName == "STYLE") {
        $("head").append(el.outerHTML);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I need to use a class name as there can be multiple style blocks that I do and do not need to "import" from the fetched markup. Also, does looping over every single element in $html to check if it's a style tag not impact performance?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure as to why this is, but it has something to do with the document model and how it works.  You can't just hold a temporary var with the html text in it, you need to put it all inside an element (like a div) that is attached to the document in some way.  This div could be hidden from view from the user.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <div></div>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('div').hide().html('<html><head><style class="test"></style></head></html>'); // From AJAX request

        var $style = $('div').find('.test');
        document.body.appendChild($style[0]);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On second thought, it's possibly because JQuery's find function uses the document.findElementById, in that case, the element must be somewhere in the document.

Comment: I think that is indeed the issue. I have tried your answer and it works! However, another problem has risen, which is that any Javascript code in the HTML markup gets executed when setting the HTML on that div. I have managed to circumvent this with help from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6660151/2472719.

The final code is http://jsfiddle.net/T6QCR/5/. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please check my answer, and take a look at the jQuery documentation. The behaviour of the jQuery function for the case you are using is different from what you are expecting.