# Extract only begining and end script tag with preg_match_all

Tags: php, html, regex

Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ..code.. </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> ..code.. </script>
<script> ..code.. </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> ..code.. </script>
```

What i would like to see:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My expression:

```
preg_match_all('/<script.*> (<\/script>)/i',$html, $result);
```

I cant get it work.

Comment: Ok, I have understand what you are trying to do. If I understand well you want to remove all between script tags. (why don't you remove script tags too?)

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6660315/1136709):

```
function stripscript($code) {
  $code = preg_replace('/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/i', '<script type="text/javascript"></script>', $code);
  return $code;
}
```

Codepad example: [here](http://codepad.org/xjjurb6x)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$html = preg_replace('~<script[^>]*>\K[^<]*(?=</script>)~i', '', $html);
```

or this for more performances:

```
$html = preg_replace('~<script[^>]*+>\K[^<]*+(?=</script>)~i', '', $html);
```

Note that if you are sure of the lowercase, you can remove the `i`.

`\K` reset the start of the match from match result.
`(?=</script>)` is a zero-width assertion that means "followed by `</string>`". It's not a part of the match result. It's only a check.

Comment: the preg_replace works, although It does not remove comments:


`<!--000-->`
`<script type="text/javascript"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="000"></script>`

Comment: Any html comment that is present in the file still appears, is it possible not to show it.

Comment: @user3076489: I think you must edit you question and post something more clear.