# Strip tags except specific <span>-s

Tags: php, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm a little stuck here. I don't know which approach is best and the most secure. I'm working with a REST API and Handlebars.js.

**Context**: I have user-generated content that *could* look like this:

```
<span class="user-link" data-id="12345" user-id="67890">
    Name    
</span>
Blablabla my comment 
<script>
    alert("malicious");
</script> 
blabla 
<b>bold</b>
<span onclick='window.location("http://maliciouswebsite");'>
    bla
</span>
```

**Goal** : When doing a POST to the API, I want to be able to strip (or encode?) all of the HTML tags, except for the `<span class="user-link">[...]</span>` one, as I want to render it as pure HTML in the comment list. Anything else should be HTML encoded and showing as text. In the case of any malicious insertion, I would also like to remove any sort of event (like 'onclick' on the span tag), and just keep my "data-id" and "user-id" attributes.

**Question** : What should my approach be here? I'm fully aware that REGEXes on HTML are very discouraged. Should I make the `<span class="user-link">[...]</span>` BBCode? Or should I stick some a simple Regex? Should I go with JS or PHP? How should I go about rendering the text safely?

Thank you so mcuh for your time! Any tip/link would immensely help.

Comment: Instead of having to word around this issue, why not change your editor to disallow HTML? You could use markdown to format the site with a restricted set of UI options (similar to how SO works) which you then convert to valid HTML on the server-side.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I've thought long and hard about your suggestion, and I think I could work something out with this, but I'm still faced with 1 problem; I need the "data-id" and "user-id" attributes. Actually, I'm using a system similar to SO, where I type it the "@" character, it gives me suggestions of names, I pick one, and I then append it to my contentEditable DIV. As far as I know, associating the "@"'s value (user name) to its user-id is something I could only be fetching from the resulted HTML (the <span>) in the contentEditable DIV. I really don't know how SO/FB do it...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are

- you could restrict the allowed input on client-side

  - instead of allowing to send HTML, restrict the input and allow less: bbcode or markdown
  - `Handlebars.SafeString()` - ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21471546/1163786
- apply input validation on server-side
- apply input validation and filtering on server-side

  - see below striptags, filtering by whitelist, blacklist
- never forget that only Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex.

---

The main topic is "Input Filtering and Validation" of incoming user input.

You have asked about a "best practice" or "how to proceed on this problem".

Its described over here:

- http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Input-Validation.html
- https://phpbestpractices.org/#sanitizing-html

> For many web apps, simply escaping HTML isn't enough. You probably
>   want to entirely remove any HTML, or allow a small subset of HTML
>   through. To do this, use the **HTML Purifier** library.
>
> But it is extremely slow for complex HTML. Consider setting up a caching solution to store the sanitized result for later use.

You find a code example for working with HTML Purifier when following the last link. The purifier uses a HTML tag whitelist/blacklisting approach. Its slow because filtering is a complex task.

There are other tools out there: http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

When you restrict the allowed input to markdown, then you could use a markdown parser to prepare the output. This will still parse the whole input, but is faster than applying whitelist/blacklist purification.