# Parse contents of script tags inside string

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
var myString = "<p>hello</p><script>console.log('hello')</script><h1>Test</h1><script>console.log('world')</script>"
```

I would like to use split to get an array with the contents of the script tags. e.g. I want my output to be:

```
["console.log('hello')", "console.log('world')"]
```

I tried doing `myString.split(/[<script></script>]/)` But did not get the expected output.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression)

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Parse the HTML instead.

Comment: I would suggest staying away from ["manual" parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and rather creating an actual DOM element from this string. You will then be able to directly access the different tags and their content. See [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro) for some more info and techniques.

Comment: @i_trope do you need to do it using split or could you do it otherwise?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[You can't parse (X)HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630).

Instead, you can parse it using [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-innerHTML).

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = myString; // Parse HTML properly (but unsafely)
```

However, this is not safe. Even if `innerHTML` doesn't run the JS inside `script` elements, malicious strings can still run arbitrary JS, e.g. with `<img src="//" onerror="alert()">`.

To avoid that problem, you can use [`DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) to create a new document, which can be used as a sandbox.

```js
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(); // Sandbox
doc.body.innerHTML = myString; // Parse HTML properly
```

Alternatively, new browsers support [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myString, 'text/html');
```

Once the HTML string has been parsed to the DOM, you can use DOM methods like [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to get all the `script` elements.

```js
var scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTagName('script');
```

Finally, [`[].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used to obtain an array with the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) of each `script` element.

```js
var arrayScriptContents = [].map.call(scriptElements, function(el) {
    return el.textContent;
});
```

---

The full code would be

```js
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(); // Sandbox
doc.body.innerHTML = myString; // Parse HTML properly
[].map.call(doc.getElementsByTagName('script'), function(el) {
    return el.textContent;
});
```

Comment: Would fragment not be enough? And would some browsers execute the script upon adding? PS: Where would the map end up as in what var?

Comment: I love when I see that epic link.

Comment: @mplungjan JS in `script` elements never run when created with `innerHTML`. However, other JS code may run, e.g. `<img src="//" onerror="alert()">`. Therefore, I used a "[sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument)".

Comment: So where are the strings then? You map and have an array [] but where is the var that holds them?

Comment: @mplungjan The call to `[].map` returns the desired array. It can be assigned to some variable: `var arr = [].map.call(/* ... */)`.

Comment: That is what I assumed but guessed OP would not grasp

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript Code:**

```
   function myFunction() {
        var str = "<p>hello</p><script>console.log('hello')</script><h1>Test</h1><script>console.log('world')</script>";

        console.log(str.match(/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/gm));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the forward slash like so: /.

```
 myString.split(/(<script>|<\/script>)/)
```