# Javascript Return HTML and css content as a string but not the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

is there a way of getting all the content of the page HTML , CSS , but exclude all the java script functions and script src?

```
        var htmlPage = $("html").html();
    console.log(htmlPage);
```

I know that will give me all of it. but I need to exclude the JS from the results

Comment: You can try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing all script tags from html with JS Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression)

Comment: Ok, I had to set the regex to non-greedy because it removed way too much HTML. Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** fixed the regex (non-greedy version)

You can try this:

```
var htmlPage = $("html").html().replace(/<script[\s\S]*?<\/script>/mig, "");
```

The regular expression should match all `<script> ... </script>` tags and replace them with nothing.

---

BTW this is kind of a lucky shot because the regex itself requires the ending `</script>` to be escaped with a `\` backslash like this: `<\/script>`.

This escape character is why the regex doesn't match itself, which would cause it to fail. So, it works because by escaping it correctly it isn't self-similar anymore.

Comment: perfect ya I was playing around with it too and I got this var htmlPage = $("html").html().replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, "");

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: My pleasure, it was fun, too :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and include the content that you want to get. For example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <!--Css links goes here--> 
  </head>
  <body>
   <!--Your content-->
    <p>Hello World</p> 
  </body>
 <script>
 //Js
 </script>
<html>
```

```js
var body = document.body.innerHTML;
var head = document.head.innerHTML;
```

Then you can concadenate or whatever you want.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting anything outside `<head>` and `<body>` tags. The HTML5 standard doesn't allow that and it breaks the page on some browsers. It also is a bad practice to write non-validating HTML in 2017. For more look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag. I don't downvote because this comment is enough of a correction. Have a nice day, sir.

Comment: You're completely right. Thank you for the information.