# Prevent iframe to reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a WYSIWYG editor (Tinymce).

I use Vue.js 1 to show a preview of the editor contents real-time. If a user types in the editor, the preview updates real-time as expected. But here is a problem.

If there is an iframe tag (Youtube video) in the preview, the video content tries to send a request to Youtube to reload as a user starts typing because the preview updates real-time. If there is only 1 video(iframe) it's ok but if there're 2 or 3 videos it gets really heavy and slow since multiple videos try to reload by themselves.

So, is there any way to make them stop sending a request to Youtube to reload when the editor contents update real-time?

Comment: You could put a debounce on the real-time reloading, so it only reloads when they stop typing, or use a 500 ms delay using `setInterval`.

Comment: [Additionally, you could strip the embed tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression) (just replace `script` with `embed`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If you are referring to a script tag in the preview there is no script tags in the preview.  If I am misunderstanding you would you please elaborate it?

Comment: In the link I gave you in the second comment, that person is trying to strip out the `<script>` tag. I was saying, you could do the same thing, but instead of `script` use `embed`.