# Drop a script if Safari is detected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to prevent a script from loading using jQuery or JavaScript for Safari only?

I have been playing with the following, but I am not getting it right:

```
if ( /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    remove script.
}
```

I was thinking to use a "throw" script. This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var cbuser = {name: '', email: '', message: ''}, access_token = 'Z2SxfM5dRhhjzKsm3Auhbi4', cburl = '//www.domain.com/';document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + cburl + 'assets/cmodule-chat/js/chatbull-init.js"></' + 'script>');</script>
```

This is in the HTML of the file at the moment.

Comment: Why would anyone want that?

Comment: Once a script is loaded it is loaded into memory, removing the html tag won't unload it.

Comment: You can do the other way round. Add the script only, if — not — Safari.

Comment: @ connexo - the script is a "online chat help" it crashes fullpage.js on safari so want to remove it

Comment: @AJAX can you explain more please. Thank you

Comment: @CBore - yes it is but answer was off topic. I will link this post to it as there is an answer to the question, which will help others.

Comment: whats the point of mark down. Clear issues with you mods sometimes. Delete all the posts instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like -

```
if (checkForChromeAndFirefox()) { 
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://somescript.js";
  $("head").append(s);
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is great, but will i lose the script on chrome and fire fox also?

Comment: No. This is what I meant. Just add the script there. You can do `(!Safari)`.

Comment: seems the script is required to be in the body, so targeting it as if it was a file is not possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression + the above fixed this. thank you for your help