# Remove script tag from html and from the DOM with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

How to remove a js script from the html and from the DOM?

To exemplify, in my html i have a div with a button:

```
<div class="tester">

    <button id="myBtn">Click me!</button>

</div>
```

And it has also this script `<script src="js/debug.js" id="debug_js"></script>`

The code of `debug.js` :

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initApp1);


function initApp1()
{

    console.log("Init App!! ");

    var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var script = document.getElementById("debug_js");

    myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

        alert("clicked!");

        $( script ).remove();

    });

} //    initApp1
```

When i do the first click, it removes the script from the html. Ok.
When i click again i expect this behaviour:
DOn't make the alert "clicked!" (actually Do nothing).

The behaviour that i'm having:
It throws the alert "clicked!" again (every time the btn is clicked)

After some search i found that:
"**By removing the  tag, you do not remove any of its objects, functions etc. from the DOM. So any action started within that  tag will prevail, even if you delete the element, that started it in the first place!**"

**So how can i remove it also from the DOM ?** (or other suggestions)

Comment: By nature it would seem (at least to me) silly to remove script functionality from the DOM, when you could simply just disable the functionality that you want from *within* the script ??  It might help to know the reasoning behind what you're trying to do ..

Comment: It's not silly because i want to load new html from ajax request and change the html content dinamically, so when the new html is appended, the old js script for the old html is not needed anymore @Zak

Comment: As you've already read, it's not possible to remove the script itself, eventhouhgt the element can be removed. In the old days there was a trick, change the src of the script to a non-existing file, afaik that's not working anymore in modern browsers (changing the src of the parsed script element doesn't load a new script).

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the script in the button click event

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var script = document.getElementById("debug_js");
    if(script){
        alert("clicked!");

        $( script ).remove();
    }
});
```

Or you can remove the event handler after clicking

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var script = document.getElementById("debug_js");

var btnHandler = function(){
    alert("clicked!");
    $( script ).remove();
    myBtn.removeEventListener("click", btnHandler);
}

myBtn.addEventListener("click", btnHandler);
```

Comment: wat i want is to remove also its content from the DOM, because i want to implement this in other "bigger" projects

Comment: The content is gone, but you wired up an event listener.  You can call removeEventListener to remove the click event if you want it gone.  Added that option to my answer

Comment: And if i want to (after removing the old js script): 1º load another html from ajax request, 2º append it to html, 3º append a new js script that has also a function with the same name for that button?

Comment: I'm not really following the logic of what you want.  Unloading and loading new scripts for the same button seems very odd to me.  There must be another way to get the end result you are looking for but I'm not quite sure what that is.

Answer (score 2):

There are two general approaches to remove all `script` tags from `HTML` with `Javascript`:

**REGEX**

```
const patt = /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script\s*>/gi
const html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
html.innerHTML =  html.innerHTML.replace(patt, '')
```

**Insert it as the innerHTML of a div**, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6660151/4791116)

But... any script which got evaluated once by the engine will stay in memory for the rest of your session. Even by removing the entire script node where the code was contained doesn't change that fact.

To get rid of the script effect you can choose at least two strategies:

- `document.write(html.innerHTML);` after cleaning html.innerHTML from scripts (see above)
- clean eventListeners by `EventTarget.removeEventListener()`