# JavaScript - Remove script tags from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When a HTML file is loaded, I want to run a script which would remove few scripts tags from the HTML file based on the user agent.

To do this I've followed this question: [Removing all script tags from html with JS Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6660151/4279257)

But couldn't achieve what I needed, the script tags are removed and they are getting downloaded.

**HTML:**

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <p></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function stripScripts(s) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = s;
            var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
            var i = scripts.length;
            while (i--) {
                scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
            }
            return div.innerHTML;
        }
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        console.log(userAgent);
        if (!userAgent.includes("Chrome")) {
            stripScripts(); // Here how can I call the present index.html?

        }
        else {
            var para = document.createElement("P");                      
            var t = document.createTextNode("You cannot view this in Chrome");      
            para.appendChild(t);                                          
            document.body.appendChild(para);
        };

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts2.js"></script> <!-- load only when the condition is met else remove it --!> 
</body>

</html>
```

When I run the `index.html` in chrome, `script2.js` is loading all the time.

Comment: well if you do not want script2.js to run than do no include it in the page. Only add it to the document when it is needed.

Comment: I do not have control on that, scripts are always included in html as it is generated build from angular cli so I need a way to strip those dynamically.

Comment: try adding script2.js in head

Comment: you can dynamically add scripts from angular lifecycle hooks

Comment: The issue with it is if it is included on the page and you can reference it, than it has already run.