# How to sanitize data in NestJs?

Tags: nestjs, sanitization

There was one question before but with no answer.
Since expresss-sanitizer is deprecated I'm wondering how to properly sanitize data in the NestJs queries?

I would probably use a global and custom pipe for that, but honestly I have no idea how could I replace string of `<script>....</script>` into properly sanitized format.

Do you know any npm packages that would help to sort that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression) question. I think your best option is using a package like [xss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss) or [strip-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-js) to strip javascript code from a string. Then wrap it in a custom pipe.

Comment: Cheers!
I thought there is a cleaner solution that this, but unfortunately I am afraid Nestjs did not provide us with a dedicated sanitizers (that would be a big advantage). Imma stick to one of these libraries.
I believe `xss` library would do the work. Gonna wrap it up in a global pipe for handling all requests. I believe that should do the work. thanks!

Comment: Nest is mostly a communication layer. It purposely does not do too much. It let's you choose other components yourself. Also, sanitizing is not always needed. Most of the time escaping html is enough.