# Removing script from HTML string using node-html-parser

Tags: node.js, node-html-parser

I have an API which receives a string containing HTML code and stores it in a database. I'm using [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) package to perform some logic on the HTML.

Among other things, I want to remove any potentially-malicious script. According to the documentation, the package should be able to do this when instructed via the `options` object (see 'Global Methods' heading in previous link).

**My code:**

```
const parser = require('node-html-parser');
const html = `<p>My text</p><script></script>`
const options = {
    blockTextElements: {
        script: false
    }
}
const root = parser.parse(html, options)
return ({ html: root.innerHTML})
```

I tried modifying the options object with `script: true`, `noscript: false`, and `noscript: true` as well, but neither removed the script tags from the html.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should be mindful that this strategy still leaves you wide open for other JavaScript injection vectors via `on*` attributes in the HTML markup itself, among others. Dependent on how you're piecing the markup back together on the tail end, you may also still be very vulnerable to markup a la `<scr<script>Ha!</script>ipt> alert(document.cookie);</script>` (h/t to [this SO thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression)). You really should re-evaluate mitigations for this type of attack dependend on your broader threat model.

Comment: A safer approach would be to use a more security-focused library like [`sanitize-html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) which is specifically geared to minimize or eliminate these potential attack vectors by allowing for the configuration of an explicit allow-list of HTML element types and attributes that fit your use case.

Comment: @esqew this is really insightful. I'll have a look into integrating this package for sanitisation. Thank you for making me aware.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the `'node-html-parser'` is kind of buggy for `script: false` but we still can use this library to work with DOM. My solution is to use `querySelectorAll` to find all the `<script>` tags and remove them so the final solution might looks like:

```
const parser =  require('node-html-parser');
let html = '<html>asdasd<script></script></html>';
//convert plain html to dom
let dom = parser.parse(html);
//select all the script tags from the DOM and remove them
dom.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(x=> x.remove());

//now DOM contains everything except script tags
//to transform DOM back to plain html we just need to use method toString() 
console.log(dom.toString());
```